# Error 2013 - Lost Connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: azure, navicat

I got this error "2013 - Lost Connection to MySQL server during query" when i tried to open a connection to Microsoft Azure using Navicat.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to fix the "Lost Connection to MySQL server during query"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Navicat. Had the exact same issue when connecting to a Azure Database for MySQL server. Worked fine after upgrading Navicat from 10.0.6 to 11.2.6.