# Pymysql and Microsoft Azure Mysql Database 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Im trying to connect to a Mysql Azure Server and Im getting the error:

```
(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

On the connect command.

I've read several similar questions here:

[Error 2013 - Lost Connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742940/error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

[Error 2013 - Lost Connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742940/error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

[pymysql,Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067378/pymysql-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

But according to the traceback my error is occurring on the `connect()`, and the questions above are more related to big queries being made to the DB.

This is the traceback:

```
  File "updateStock.py", line 125, in <module>
    main()
  File "updateStock.py", line 65, in main
    db = connection.connect()
  File "updateStock.py", line 22, in connect
    db="mydb")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 852, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 656, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 702, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

And this is my code for connecting:

```
class DB:
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host="myserver.database.azure.com",
                                    user="usert@myserver.mysql.database.azure.com",
                                    passwd="****",
                                    port=3306,
                                    db="mydb")
        return self
    def get_cursor(self):
        return self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)

def main():
    # try:
    connection = DB()
    db = connection.connect()
    cursor = db.get_cursor()
```

Can anyone help me spot the problem?

Comment: Just double checking your connection string. The user parameter should be specified as "user@servername". You do not need ".mysql.database.azure.com" for the usernname.

Comment: Yes I did that. I managed to solve it by changing the pymysql library to mysql-connector-python-rf